# How to display one div and hide all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a div on each button click and also want to hide the other all divs how I can do it.

**HTML**

```
<div id=a style="display:none">1</diV>
<div id=b style="display:none">2</diV>
<div id=c style="display:none">3</diV>
<div id=d style="display:none" >4</diV>

<input type=button value=1 id=w>
<input type=button value=2 id=x>
<input type=button value=3 id=y>
<input type=button value=4 id=z>
```

**jQuery**

```
$​('#w').live('click', function () {
    $('#a').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#x').live('click', function () {
    $('#b').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#y').live('click', function () {
    $('#c').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#z').live('click', function () {
    $('#d').css('display', 'block');
});
```

​ http://jsfiddle.net/6UcDR/

Comment: Just so you know, all attributes must have quotes. `id="a"` as oppposed to `id=a`. (`id` must start with a letter)

Comment: I am not sure about JQuery, but I am using dojo and there must be similar way to do this in JQuery. When I am displaying one div, I stores its id in global var. Now I have 2 class for hiding and displaying div. When user presses button, using the value in global var I get the reference of div currently displayed and remove the display class and add hide class. And to display the div, I remove the hide class and add display class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start by hiding all other div's, then showing the one you want to be shown.

```
$​('#w').live('click', function(){
    $('div').hide();
    $('#a').show();
});
```

Comment: If there are any other divs on the page, they will be unnecessarily hidden, for the solution refer my answer

Answer (score 3):

In your JSFiddle, you are using jQuery 1.7.2. If you are using this version in your real app, you should **not** be using `$.live()`, but use `$.on()` instead - the former is deprecated in favour of the latter.

The simplest and cleanest way to solve your problem would be to wrap both your buttons and divs in containers, and use `$.index()` to associate a button with a div:

```
<div class="showThese">
    <div id="a" style="display:none">1</div>
    <div id="b" style="display:none">2</div>
    <div id="c" style="display:none">3</div>
    <div id="d" style="display:none" >4</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="1" id="w">
    <input type="button" value="2" id="x">
    <input type="button" value="3" id="y">
    <input type="button" value="4" id="z">
</div>
```

Note that your attributes *must* be quoted, as in the above HTML.

Then, in JavaScript, you only need to bind one delegated event to the buttons container. I'll use `$.on()` in this case:

```
$('div.buttons').on('click', 'input', function() {
    var divs = $('div.showThese').children();

    divs.eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBfEK/) is a demo.

The above method does away with having to use IDs and other attributes, however you will need to be careful if you want other elements in the containers, as `$.index()` will  begin to fail if you do.

Comment: I like the use of siblings here. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

`live` is deprecated, use `on`

```
$​('input').on('click', function(){

    var index = $(this).index();
    $('div').hide().eq(index).show();

});
```

example from jQuery.com:

```
function notify() { alert("clicked"); }
$("button").on("click", notify);
```

Comment: `live` and your `on` variant are not the same.

Comment: @VisioN See my update, it can be replaced without any modifications

Comment: Hm, nothing really changed. Check delegated-events approach in docs.

Answer (score 1):

If understand you correctly, it should be just setting the display:none for the divs before showing your specific div.

```
    $('#w').live('click', function(){
        $('div').css('display','none');
        $('#a').css('display','block');

    });

    $('#x').live('click', function(){
         $('div').css('display','none');
        $('#b').css('display','block');
    });

    $('#y').live('click', function(){
         $('div').css('display','none');
        $('#c').css('display','block');
    });

    $('#z').live('click', function(){
         $('div').css('display','none');
        $('#d').css('display','block');
    });

​
```

Comment: If there are any other divs on the page, they will be unnecessarily hidden, for the solution refer my answer

Comment: @Playmaker, you are correct. I was only giving the solution to the given code. It can be easily extended to target the specific divs. Your solution must eliminate that the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/6UcDR/2/ Is this the thing that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **jQuery**-

```
$​('#w').click(function(){
$('#a').show()
$('#b,#c,#d').hide()
});

$('#x').click(function(){
$('#b').show();
$('#a,#c,#d').hide()
});

$('#y').click(function(){
$('#c').show();
$('#b,#a,#d').hide()
});

$('#z').click(function(){
$('#d').show();
$('#b,#c,#d').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the divs u want to show or hide
eg:

```
<div id=a class="hide" style="display:none">1</diV>
```

And then add the following statement to each onclick function

```
 $('.hide').css('display','none'); /* Replace .hide with whatever class name u have chosen*/
```

To see the answer in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6UcDR/1/